# How to replicate iptables rules in windows

Tags: windows, networking, windows-firewall

I want to replicate a specific `iptables` rules in Windows 11:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags RST,ACK -j DROP
```

It seems that Windows Firewall doesn't have this feature and Windows in general doesn't have native app that can replicate `iptables`

What are my alternatives?

Comment: Such functionality would have to implemented using a Windows Filtering Platform Callout Driver.

Comment: The best alternative might be to use a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: I'm looking for a native solution as I will deploying those to a low-end machine, but if there's no direct alternative I might be out of luck.